# Как заменить значение в одном теге значением из другого тега в xml файле. c#

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

Было

```
<doms>
    <dom><autor>Иван</autor><bd>111111</bd><xxx>555</xxx><data>222222</data></dom>
    <dom><autor>Николай</autor><bd>3333</bd><xxx>555</xxx><data>44444</data>
    </dom>
</doms>
```

Стало бы

```
<doms>
    <dom><autor>Иван</autor><bd>111111</bd><xxx>555</xxx><data>111111</data></dom>
    <dom><autor>Николай</autor><bd>3333</bd><xxx>555</xxx><data>3333</data>
    </dom>
</doms>
```

Если возможно, то скромный код... замены

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Обновил вопрос

Файл `doms.xml`

```
<doms>
  <dom><autor>Иван</autor><bd>111111</bd><xxx>555</xxx><data>222222</data></dom>
  <dom><autor>Николай</autor><bd>33333</bd><xxx>555</xxx><data>444444</data></dom>
</doms>
```

---

```
var root = "C:\\Temp\\";
var xe = XElement.Load(root + "doms.xml");
foreach (var dom in xe.Descendants("dom"))
  dom.Element("data").Value = dom.Element("bd").Value;
xe.Save(root + "doms.new.xml");
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну вот вам прагматичное решение:

```
var s = @"<doms>
          <autor>Иван</autor><bd>111111</bd><data>222222</data>
          <autor>Николай</autor><bd>33333</bd><data>444444</data>
          </doms>";
var xml = XDocument.Parse(s);

var data = xml.Descendants("data"); // материализация не нужна, т. к. последовательность
foreach (var datum in data)         // не изменяется
    datum.Value = ((XElement)datum.PreviousNode).Value;

var result = xml.ToString();
```

Результат:

```
<doms>
  <autor>Иван</autor>
  <bd>111111</bd>
  <data>111111</data>
  <autor>Николай</autor>
  <bd>33333</bd>
  <data>33333</data>
</doms>
```

---

Обновление. Для произвольного порядка подойдёт такое:

```
var s = @"<doms>
          <autor>Иван</autor><bd>111111</bd><xxx>555</xxx><data>222222</data>
          <autor>Николай</autor><bd>33333</bd><xxx>555</xxx><data>444444</data>
          </doms>";
var xml = XDocument.Parse(s);

var data = xml.Descendants("data");
var bds = xml.Descendants("bd");
foreach (var pair in data.Zip(bds, (datum, bd) => new {datum, bd}))
    pair.datum.Value = pair.bd.Value;

var result = xml.ToString();
```

---

Обновление. Окей, новый XML можно обрабатывать и с предыдущим кодом, он работает. А можно и так:

```
var s = @"<doms>
            <dom><autor>Иван</autor><bd>111111</bd><xxx>555</xxx><data>222222</data></dom>
            <dom><autor>Николай</autor><bd>3333</bd><xxx>555</xxx><data>44444</data>
            </dom>
          </doms>";
var xml = XDocument.Parse(s);

foreach (var dom in xml.Descendants("dom"))
    dom.Elements("data").Single().Value = dom.Elements("bd").Single().Value;
```

---

Обновление: последний сниппет можно упростить до

```
foreach (var dom in xml.Descendants("dom"))
    dom.Element("data").Value = dom.Element("bd").Value;
```

Но это уже есть в более раннем ответе.

Comment: Извиняюсь, теги не обязательно рядом будут стоять

Comment: @Андрей: С точки зрения XML это одно и то же. Пробелы и переводы строк между тегами в XML — незначимые.

Comment: Просто я не вижу в коде тег '<bd>' и не могу понять как все работает

Comment: @Андрей: `datum.PreviousNode` ссылается на предыдущий узел. Для узла `<data>222222</data>` предыдущий `<bd>111111</bd>`.

Comment: @Андрей: Или вы имеете в виду, что порядок тегов может быть другой? Тогда дайте пример возможного XML.

Comment: @Андрей: добавил в ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Файл `doms.xml`

```
<root>
  <doms>
    <autor>Иван</autor><bd>111111</bd><xxx>555</xxx><data>222222</data>
    <autor>Николай</autor><bd>33333</bd><xxx>555</xxx><data>444444</data>
  </doms>
</root>
```

---

```
// #r "System.Xml.Linq"
using System.Xml.Linq;

var root = "c:\\temp\\";
var xe = XElement.Load(root + "doms.xml");
foreach (var doms in xe.Descendants("doms"))
    foreach (var a in doms.Elements("autor")) {
        var data = a.ElementsAfterSelf("data").First();
        var bd = a.ElementsAfterSelf("bd").First();
        data.Value = bd.Value;
    }
xe.Save(root + "doms.new.xml");
```

Результат `doms.new.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
    <doms>
        <autor>Иван</autor>
        <bd>111111</bd>
        <xxx>555</xxx>
        <data>111111</data>
        <autor>Николай</autor>
        <bd>33333</bd>
        <xxx>555</xxx>
        <data>33333</data>
    </doms>
</root>
```

Comment: Хм, это для случая, когда порядок элементов фиксирован. Автор вроде говорил, что не обязательно в комментариях.

Comment: @VladD _"это для случая, когда порядок элементов фиксирован."_ -- т.е. может быть `bd`, `data` или `data`, `bd` -- исправил ответ.

Comment: Угу, остроумно.

Comment: Накосячил со структурой xml. Обновил вопрос

Comment: @Андрей _"Накосячил со структурой xml. Обновил вопрос "_ -- ок. добавил [ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/488220/196972)

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{

    [XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
    [XmlRoot(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public class doms
    {
        [XmlElement("autor", typeof(string))]
        [XmlElement("bd", typeof(string))]
        [XmlElement("data", typeof(string))]
        [XmlChoiceIdentifier("ItemsElementName")]
        public string[] Items { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("ItemsElementName")]
        [XmlIgnore]
        public ItemsChoiceType[] ItemsElementName { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlType(IncludeInSchema = false)]
    public enum ItemsChoiceType{autor,bd,data}


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = "pathToXML.xml";

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(doms));

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
            var result = (doms)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

[Документация](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlchoiceidentifierattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)